# PHP Open Source eCommerce Software

Tags: php, open-source, e-commerce

I hope you are good today, my query is a simple one i am searching for an open source ecommerce solution that can be extended with my own modules etc.

*after scouring google there are loads of open source solutions and different websites recommend different solutions.*

I trust the community of stack far more than random websites on google, so can you please make recommendations on systems you have previously used and how you found them on an overall.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a big application, you could take a look at [**Magento**](http://www.magentocommerce.com/) : it's a robust solution, with both a community and an entreprise version.

Another idea *(that might be lighter)* might be [**PrestaShop**](http://www.prestashop.com/).

Some might suggest you [osCommerce](http://www.oscommerce.com/), but it's an old software -- and even if it had much success some years ago, it doesn't really anymore now *(I've never used it myself, but some colleagues of mine have worked with it -- and have since switched to Magento)*.

Comment: thanks for the recommendation i will research both.

Comment: Having used Magento for some work projects I have to say that it is very extensible and customisable once you get your head around the hideous XML templates. Big problem we found with it is that it eats servers for breakfast. Even with full caching enabled it uses a lot of ram and cpu cycles. But it will do everything you could possibly want it to.

Comment: I was going to write exactly the same :). Btw, I am using Magento and I am in love with it. It has a lot of features and it is fully extensible. My vote is for Magento.

Comment: Thanks for your responses *still investigating* :)

Comment: @chapagain @Adam Pointer @Pascal Martin do you have a knowledge base you consult for support on Magneto ? Obviously as you guys have been using far long than i would of had, you should of already established the necessary knowledge bases for the software :)

Comment: In the end i went with Magneto thanks for the advise much appreciated !!!! :)

Comment: I used all of them, in my opinion PrestaShop is just great for small to medium websites!

Answer (score 0):

i use osCommerce but it is "old software" but i have be with it a long time and know it well. for someone new looking at getting in to it i would look more to PrestaShop. osCommerce still have its good points in there is a lot of info on the web so it is not hard to find a fix when you need one.

The best bet mite be to download some and have a play for yourself :) hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I would try [www.oscmax.com](http://www.oscmax.com) - it is a osCommerce fork which has all of the functionality most shop owners would need.  There is a new release coming out now (currently Release Candidate going through final testing and bug fixing)

Why oscmax?  It is truely open-source ... no purchasing of extra modules etc.  The 6,000+ modules coded for osCommerce will install into it which gives the average user an almost unlimited ability to tailor the store to their specific needs.

[Friendly and active forums](http://www.oscmax.com/forums/) and an active development cycle.

I would avoid Magento - it has a very complex code structure (especially the templates) and is very resource hungry (you will need a dedicated server to run it).

PrestaShop and OpenCart are probably the next best but I prefer to use the work already done on the osCommerce community and not having to pay for additonal module (which tend to come with very poor support)

So all in all - I would give [www.osCmax.com](http://www.oscmax.com) a go ... [test the new v2.5 RC1 not the old version.](http://www.oscmax.com/blog/michael_s/oscmax_v25_release_candidate_available_download)